# Is there a typo in the C++ Assignment Operator tutorial?

Tags: c++

[This](http://brskari.wordpress.com/2011/02/24/c-assignment-operator-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-not-check-for-self-assignment/) is a good tutorial that illustrates the correct way to design C++ assignment operator.

In the end, the author provides the following alternative implementation for the operator as follows:

```
1   Foo& operator=(Foo rhs)
2   {
3       swap(rhs);
4       return *this;
5   }
```

Based on the [swap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/swap/), the line `3` should be `swap(*this, rhs)` or `swap(rhs, *this)`.

**Question**> Is my understanding correct?

Thank you

Comment: The article mentions "Because moving pointers will not throw an exception, we can write a swap() method that swaps the contents of two Foo objects that has the no-throw guarantee. Then, we can write the whole copy constructor as follows..", so swap here is assumed to be a member function.

Answer (score 4):

The code-snippet that you quote is introduced by this explanation:

> Because moving pointers will not throw an exception, we can write a `swap()` method that swaps the contents of two `Foo` objects that has the no-throw guarantee. Then, we can write the whole copy constructor as follows:

So the `swap` in the code-snippet is that member function named `swap`, not the standalone function named `std::swap` that was used earlier in the tutorial.